# ffmpeg problems (mpeg1video -> ?)

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert various video files from .mpeg to .ogg theora videos. This command works fine when I test it in its own program, but fails to run properly inside the program it was intended for. I don't understand what's breaking here. Adding a `-vcodec` flag causes other errors.

Here is the function I am using to run `ffmpeg`:

```
 * This method converts a file to Ogg Theora video using ffmpeg.
 * 
 * @param f
 *            The file to encode. (Assumes that the file has a .mpeg
 *            extension. If the file doesn't have this, the method will
 *            fail.) 
 * @param nice The niceness of the created ffmpeg
 *            priority.
 * @return converter The process that represents ffmpeg working on the file.
 */
private Process encodeFileAsTheora(File f, int nice) {
    Process converter = null;
    try {
        String targetFileName = f.getAbsolutePath()
                .replace(".mpeg", ".ogg");
        // mLogger.log(Level.INFO,
        // "Now attempting to convert " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        String[] ffmpegCommand = { "nice", "-n", Integer.toString(nice),
                "ffmpeg", "-i", f.getAbsolutePath(), targetFileName };
        converter = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpegCommand);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return converter;
}
```

And here is its `getErrorStream()` output to the logger:

*NON RELEVANT CONTENT REMOVED*

configuration: --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/libvpx --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/x264 --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/x264 --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/libvpx --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --yasmexe=/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/yasm/yasm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SEVERE: DDCS -   configuration:
>   --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/libvpx --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/x264 --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/x264 --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/libvpx --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --yasmexe=/home/user/trunk/cpp_src/ffmpeg-source/yasm/yasm

Your ffmpeg is not compiled with libtheora support, so you can't encode to ogg/theora.